# Add an API to a specific project inside a SwaggerHub organisation

Tags: swaggerhub

It's easy to upload an API to an organisation via SwaggerHub CLI:
`swaggerhub api:create OWNER/API_NAME/[VERSION]`

But I need to upload an API under some project inside an organisation.

In all examples from https://github.com/SmartBear/swaggerhub-cli
there is no "project" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwaggerHub CLI does not support projects yet. There's an [existing feature request](https://github.com/SmartBear/swaggerhub-cli/issues/199) for that.

You can, however, use [SwaggerHub Registry API](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/swagger-hub/registry-api/1.0.63#/Projects/addSpecToProjectV2) to add your uploaded API to a specific project.

```
curl -X PUT https://api.swaggerhub.com/projects/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/apis/API_NAME -H "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY"
```

If you use self-hosted SwaggerHub On-Premise, the request would be as follows and requires v. 1.26 or later. Add the `-k` flag if your instance uses a self-signed or privately signed certificate.

```
curl -X PUT http(s)://YOUR_SERVER/v1/projects/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/apis/API_NAME -H "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that suits my needs, but here comes another question - how to use this api in case of custom `SwaggerHub URL`?

Comment: Updated the answer.